# cloud foundry giving 404 after application deployment but works intermittently after just a server restart

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, cloud-foundry

I have developed a web application with spring boot which is being deployed on cloud foundry using pivotal.
Issue1:
The problem is, when application is deployed I get a message "Container became healthy" which I suppose signifies that war has been deployed in the tomcat container inside cloud foundry. And everything is working as expected and application is up.
Now when I hit health/env/applcation url it gives me 404 in logs, but if I simply just restart the server the application is up and works fine for all URL's.
Issue 2:
Sometimes the application crashes in cloud foundry and as expected in a PaaS application the server starts again and shows the same message as "Container became healthy". But the same problem persists in this case is that the URL's are never found. Thus in case of failure recovery everytime the application gives 404 for the URL's that were working earlier, which eventually work when I simply restart.

I have updated the memory_heuristics in manifest.yml and I dont see any logs due to out of memory the only thing I see is for URL's /health or /env it just moves from 200 to 404.

Comment: Try getting logs. cf logs [appName] --recent before restarting the app.

Comment: The app restart on its own after crash and after restart this issue is faced